# PHAssetManager ignoring targetSize when requesting image?

Tags: ios, swift, image, photos, phasset

I have a list of `PHAssets` that I need to get images from of a certain size.

To test this out, I give the size to be the size of the device screen

```
        let manager = PHImageManager.default()
        let option = PHImageRequestOptions()
        option.isSynchronous = true

        for asset in assets {
            manager.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height), contentMode: .aspectFit, options: option, resultHandler: {(result, info)->Void in

                //prints the proper bounds for a screen
                print("width and height \(UIScreen.main.bounds.width) \(UIScreen.main.bounds.height)")

                //prints 2304.0 3072.0 for width and height respectively
                print("result size \(result!.size.width) \(result!.size.height)\n")

                self.photos.append(result!)
            })
        }
```

I need the resulting photos to be cut to the size I specify, but they're off by over 2000 pixels. How do I resolve this?

Comment: I don't have access to the docs at the moment but I seem to recall that when you do a synchronous fetch of the image, you may get multiple results per image. The info in the callback can tell you if the given result is the final result or not.

Comment: @matt It means exactly what it sounds like. The size of the actual image is over 2000 pixels greater than the size requested

Take a look at the comments above each print statement in the code. The printed values are right there

Comment: @rmaddy No, not for `isSynchronous=true`

Comment: @matt, its on a background thread...

Comment: @matt Right. It's when it's asynchronous that is does what I stated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
option.resizeMode = .exact
```

[Per Apple:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phimagemanager/1616964-requestimage)

> To serve your request more quickly, Photos may provide an image that
>   is slightly larger than the target size—either because such an image
>   is already cached or because it can be generated more efficiently.

Since you want a specific size, then set the above option to force the request to respect your size.

[Option](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phimagerequestoptionsresizemode)

```
case exact
```

> Photos resizes the image to match the target size exactly.